python don't see virtual memory on usb drive
I have a Python program that processes MP3 files into spectrograms. Processing a large number of spectrograms causes the virtual memory on my laptop to fill up very quickly, so I wanted to use a USB drive as additional virtual memory.
I set it up in Windows 10 as virtual memory, but during the program's execution, the system doesn't use this drive at all, even when I set it as the only option for virtual memory.
Does this mean it's simply not possible to use a USB drive as virtual memory, even though Windows provides this option?

After processing each file store the image on disk and free the memory. And run process consecutively or in small batches. Flash drives are not for virtual memory because of limited cycles of write.
